# Rails 5 run puma and simple xmlrpc server at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml-rpc, puma, ruby-on-rails-5

My rails app needs a `XMLRPC` server. But There when I try:

```
rails s
```

Only `XMLRPC` server starts and puma does not start. What I have done in my `config.rb` file is:

```
require_relative 'config/environment'
require "xmlrpc/server"


server = XMLRPC::Server.new( 1234 )
server.add_handler('my_test.test') { |msg|

   "responce for #{msg}"
}
server.serve # HERE IS WHERE APP STUCKS WITH XMLRPC
run Rails.application
```

Is there any idea to perform this?