# how to use Puma/ruby to implement xml-rpc server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml-rpc, puma, ruby-on-rails-5

Is there any way to build `xml-rpc` server on top of `puma` application server? By default `require xmlrpc/server` uses `webrick`.

Answer (score 0):

the builtin ruby `xmlrpc/server` library is using the builtin webserver library `webrick`. AFAIK there is no extensibility in the regard of switching the webserver implementation.

reading your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435969/rails-5-run-puma-and-simple-xmlrpc-server-at-the-same-time) i assume that you probably need to deploy the xmlrpc server alongside your rails application.

the library comes with different implementations ie cgi, mod-ruby etc, maybe one of those is helpful to get started: https://github.com/ruby/xmlrpc/blob/master/lib/xmlrpc/server.rb